# Prevent partial view from loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How can i prevent a partial view from being loaded by typing http://mydomain.com/site/edit/1 Is there any way of doing this?

/Martin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you load your partials through Ajax then you can check if the request HTTP header `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` is present and its value is equals to `XMLHttpRequest`.

When a request is made through the browser that header is not present

Here is a very simple implementation of an Action Filter attribute that does the job for you

```
public class CheckAjaxRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string AJAX_HEADER = "X-Requested-With";

    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext ) {
        bool isAjaxRequest = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[AJAX_HEADER] != null;
        if ( !isAjaxRequest ) {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Unauthorized" };
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it to decorate any action where you want to check if the request is an ajax request

```
[HttpGet]
[CheckAjaxRequest]
public virtual ActionResult ListCustomers() {
}
```

Comment: well never mind I found it Request.Headers.Get("X-Requested-With") ;o)

Comment: Please have a look at my answer edit for implementation details :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute is what you're looking for.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Edit( int? id )
{
   var item = _service.GetItem(id ?? 0);
   return PartialView( new EditModel(item) )
}
```

Phil Haack has an article using it [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)

Comment: I'm sure it does what its supposed to do but this dosent work when i make a ajax call to get the partial view.

Comment: ChildActionOnly doesn't prevent to use Ajax request: "Any method that is marked with ChildActionOnlyAttribute can be called only with the Action or RenderAction HTML extension methods." . Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx