# In ASP.NET MVC, is it possible to limit an action to be called only through RenderAction and not from the browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some actions that are only called from Html.RenderAction and I'd like to prevent these actions from being called directly using a URL.

Is it possible to see that the current request was made from a call to RenderAction? In that case I could create an IActionFilter for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent partial view from loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361742/prevent-partial-view-from-loading)

Comment: Vote to close, answer is: use the ChildActionOnlyAttribute

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute.